# SQL decimal values getting inserted as ints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a query which returns decimals, then inserting those decimals into a table variable.  When I query the table variable I get integers.  Can anyone see why this is happening and how to correct?  Using Sql Server 2000.

```
DECLARE @Nov Table(custCode varchar(10), PromiseAvg decimal, ShipAvg decimal )

INSERT INTO @Nov
SELECT  JM.CustomerCode
  , isnull(AVG(Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(startDate, 0), ISNULL(PromiseDate, 0)) As Decimal)),0) As PromiseAvg
  , isnull(AVG(Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(startDate, 0), ISNULL(BOL.ShipDate, 0)) As Decimal)),0) As ShipAvg
from jobitems JI
LEFT JOIN jobmaster JM ON JI.Job_Number = JM.JobNumber
LEFT JOIN dbo.NCL_BOLDetails BD ON JM.JobNumber = BD.JobNumber AND JI.Item_Code = BD.ItemNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.NCL_BOLs BOL ON BD.BOLID = BOL.BOLID
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN '20091101' AND '20091130'    
Group By JM.CustomerCode, JM.CustLongName
Order By JM.CustomerCode

Select * from @Nov
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a scale and precision for your decimals in the table variable.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @Nov TABLE(
custCode VARCHAR(10), 
PromiseAvg decimal(18,8), 
ShipAvg decimal(18,8) )
```

or whatever scale and precision is appropriate for you. I just tested on SQL Server 2008 and it looks as though `decimal(18,0)` is the default if this is not specified in a `create table` statement.

Also do the same with your `cast`s

```
... 
isnull(AVG(Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(startDate, 0), ISNULL(PromiseDate, 0)) 
As decimal(18,8))),0) As PromiseAvg,
....
```

Comment: Actually, it works by defining this in the table variable, without even putting it on the casts.  Thanks, I'll accept as soon as the time expires.